# Python re.split

Tags: python, regex

For the following code,

```
import re
n = '.172..16.52.207,172.16.52.117'
s = re.split(',+|\.+',n)
print s
```

why is the first element of `s` a blank, i.e. `''` ?

Comment: What would you expect it to be?

Comment: Because the first char is `.` that is matched with the splitting pattern.

Comment: I would expect it to be 172, because I've specified the greedy + sign in the delimiter

Answer (score 0):

The first element is everything between the beginning of the string and the first `.`. There are no such characters, so it is `''`. `n[2]` should be blank as well, because there is nothing between the second `.` and the third.

Comment: Is it at all possible to get the first element to be 172 using regex?